# ocultar scripts de bootstrap en una pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

hola buenas es mi primera vez que comento por aqui, tengo un problema con bootstrap en mi blog. Tengo un blog donde la mayoria de las entradas tienen codigos bootstrap y funcionan correctamente. Hoy al crear un nuevo post que lleva un codigo ajeno a bootstrap no me funciona correctamente o mejor dicho (no funciona) lo he probado en un blog de pruebas y va perfecto.

mi pregunta es: hay algun metodo o codigo donde pueda anular el bootstrap en ese post en concreto?

Solo seria para ese articulo y que siga funcionando en el resto del blog.

no se si hay algun code block o algo similar, muchas gracias espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: hola gracias bro por tu respuesta, noo haber, lo que necesito es que ese post bootstrap este bloqueado mediante agun codigo o algo y no funcione. pero si en el resto del blog.